# Misunderstanding of ADD instruction in assembly or program exit value

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

Tinkering with assembly language again on a 64bit Linux computer, although that shouldn't make a difference.

I will copy my program and talk my way through it. Currently I don't get the answer I would expect. Here we go:

```
global _start

    section .data
v1 dq 151    ; first variable points to memory location containing "151d"
v2 dq 310    ; uint64_t v2 = 310d
sum dq 0

    section .text
_start:

mov rax, 9       ; rax now contains 9
add [v1], rax    ; v1 now points to a memory location containing 151 + 9 = 160

mov rax, [v2]    ; rax contains the value 310
add rax, 10      ; rax contains the value 310 + 10 = 320
add rax, [v1]    ; rax contains the value 320 + 160 = 480
mov [sum], rax   ; sum now points to a memory location containing the value 480

mov eax, 1       ; system call to "exit"=1
mov ebx, [sum]   ; return value of program is 480
int 0x080        ; call the system interrupt to terminate program
```

Then to run my program, I do this:

```
./main.exec; echo $?
```

The output is:

```
224
```

Not 480? I am guessing I have misunderstood how `add` works, or have misunderstood how to return exit codes to the OS. Am I correct about that?

Comment: Suggestion: step through the code with GDB: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~cpatel2/links/310/nasm/gdb_help.shtml.  I think you'll see that your code is working correctly ... but 480 > 256.  And 480-256=224 :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Probably should learn gdb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of guaranteed-to-be-supported exit codes on Linux is 0-255, inclusive.  The higher bits of the exit status are reserved in order to convey other information regarding the program's termination.  480 falls outside this range, so the actual exit code is undefined.

However, most implementations will simply truncate the exit code, which is what is happening here: 480 mod 256 = 224.